# Player Shooting using blend tree and C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using C# and Unity for a shooter game. My code works, but I'd like to tweak it. I have this on a blend tree and am using which direction the player is in to fire the bullet. The problem is, if you rapidly change directions, the player doesn't always shoot. I found this to be because the full value of 1 or -1, isn't always being achieved. If I put "less than or equal to" as opposed to "equals (==)", the bullets fire all the time as it is always "less than" at that point. Is there a different way of doing this?
Thank you in advance.

Example of my code, these are only 2 directions to save space, it is a 4 directional sprite. I apologize if the code is broken up, I don't know how to show it properly here.

```html
if (myAnimator.GetFloat("DirectionX") == -1f)
                        {
                            shotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
                            GameObject b = (Instantiate(bulletLeft, shotPoint.position + -transform.right, Quaternion.identity));
                            b.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(-transform.right * speed);
                        }

                        if (myAnimator.GetFloat("DirectionY") == 1f)
                        {
                            shotTime = Time.time + timeBetweenShots;
                            GameObject b = (Instantiate(bulletUp, shootUpPoint.position + transform.up, Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 90)));
                            b.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(transform.up * speed);
                        }
```

Comment: Floating point numbers are inherently approximations. Equality checks, therefore, are generally meaningless in this context. Equality can only be used with fixed point numbers like int, decimal, long. In short, if you are ok with approximations, use floating point because of much better performance; if you need precision, use fixed point.

Comment: You can use the less or equal but you have to exclude 0 and beyond, i.e. dir > 0.0f && dir <= 1.0f or dir < 0.0f && dir >= -1.0f

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your looking for discreet integer values:

```
int dirX = Mathf.RoundToInt(myAnimator.GetFloat("DirectionX"))
if(dirX == 1)
  //etc
```